# How to check the length of decimal types with fluent validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation, decimal, fluent

I want a decimal type variable to be greater than zero with fluent validation. How can I do this control with fluent validation?

- Daily rental fee must be greater than zero

*** DailyPrice is decimal type

```
public class CarValidator : AbstractValidator<Car>
{
    public CarValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Name).MinimumLength(2);
        RuleFor(p => p.DailyPrice).MinimumLength(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
RuleFor(p => p.DailyRentalFee).GreaterThan(0);
```